# fs.writeFileSync is not working in cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am facing an issue in google cloud function while executing the following code

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
let data = "Test";
fs.writeFileSync("text.txt", data);
console.log (fs.readFileSync("text.txt", "utf8"));
```

Result:
EROFS: read-only file system, open 'text.txt'

Comment: Google cloud function instances [run with a readonly filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not recommended to use local file system in Cloud Function there is a possibility to use `/tmp` folder. So you can only write file to this folder.
[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) mentions few things to remember using temporary directory

> The only writeable part of the filesystem is the /tmp directory, which you can use to store temporary files in a function instance. This is a local disk mount point known as a "tmpfs" volume in which data written to the volume is stored in memory. Note that it will consume memory resources provisioned for the function.

And there is [Tips & Tricks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#always_delete_temporary_files) well to delete the temporary files as it may cause some future problems:

> Local disk storage in the temporary directory is an in-memory filesystem. Files that you write consume memory available to your function, and sometimes persist between invocations. Failing to explicitly delete these files may eventually lead to an out-of-memory error and a subsequent cold start.

Comment: It might worth noting that you can't rely on files written to the `/tmp` filesystem being always available at every run. As the cloud function scales, new instances may be spawned on different VMs, so the file once written to the `/tmp` filesystem may seem to magically disappear, only to appear at a later time, depending on which instance got the request.

Comment: The correct folder is `/tmp` and not `./tmp`. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: True, thanks @JohnHanley, corrected